# Column-dependent bounds in torch.clamp

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I would like to do something similar to np.clip on PyTorch tensors on a 2D array. More specifically, I would like to clip each column in a specific range of value (column-dependent). For example, in numpy, you could do:

```
x = np.array([-1,10,3])
low = np.array([0,0,1])
high = np.array([2,5,4])
clipped_x = np.clip(x, low, high)

clipped_x == np.array([0,5,3]) # True
```

I found torch.clamp, but unfortunately it does not support multidimensional bounds (only one scalar value for the entire tensor). Is there a "neat" way to extend that function to my case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not as neat as `np.clip`, but you can use [`torch.max`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/torch.html#torch.max) and [`torch.min`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/torch.html#torch.min):

```
In [1]: x
Out[1]:
tensor([[0.9752, 0.5587, 0.0972],
        [0.9534, 0.2731, 0.6953]])
```

Setting the lower and upper bound per column

```
l = torch.tensor([[0.2, 0.3, 0.]])
u = torch.tensor([[0.8, 1., 0.65]])
```

Note that the lower bound `l` and upper bound `u` are 1-by-3 tensors (2D with singleton dimension). We need these dimensions for `l` and `u` to be [broadcastable](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/notes/broadcasting.html#broadcasting-semantics) to the shape of `x`.
Now we can clip using `min` and `max`:

```
clipped_x = torch.max(torch.min(x, u), l)
```

Resulting with

```
tensor([[0.8000, 0.5587, 0.0972],
        [0.8000, 0.3000, 0.6500]])
```

Comment: Keep in mind the upper and lower limits have to be the same type as the tensor being clamped

Comment: Isn't this notably more computational expensive than using in particular the in-place function of clamp_?

Comment: @Sibylse I'm not sure this is more computationally heavy - basically it implements the same set of `min`, `max` operations except the bounds are now not fixed and change with each row. Indeed, since `clamp_` is more "specific" it earned an "in-place" implementation that should be more efficient - memory-wise.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone, who is having the same problem like me a few minutes ago:

For about two years it is also possible to have column-dependent bounds in torch.clamp (see [PR](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/52695)):

```
In: x = torch.randn(2, 3)
        print(x)

Out: tensor([[-0.2069, 1.4082, 0.2615],
             [0.6478, 0.0883, -0.7795]])
```

Setting a lower and upper bound:

```
lower = torch.Tensor([[-1., 0., 0.]])
upper = torch.Tensor([[0., 1., 1.]])
```

Now you can simply use `torch.clamp` as follows:

```
In: clamped_x = torch.clamp(x, min=lower, max=upper)
    print(clamped_x)

Out: tensor([[-0.2069, 1.0000, 0.2615],
             [0.0000, 0.0883, 0.0000]])
```

I hope that helps :)